# HP Proliant Microserver N40L Ethernet Throttling

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ethernet, samba, spideroak

I’ve recently set up a HP Proliant Microserver with Ubuntu 22.04 Spideroak One and Samba for my home server.

The Ethernet adapter supports up to a Gbps which works fine for my internet and transfer speeds. My problem seems to be that my download speed is limited to around 30 megabits per second. My internet speeds are well over 300 megabits per second, so I’m not entirely sure why this could be happening.

Could it be that Spideroak is throttling its download speed or is there something else going wrong?

Comment: Download speeds _from where to where_? From the server? To the server? Is the other "end" on the same LAN, or is the download being done over Internet?

Comment: Apologies, download speeds from Spideroak are seemingly throttled compared to a laptop on the same network doing the same download from the Spideroak servers.